# JSF2 Why are some concepts identified by an ID while other stuff is identified by the classname

Tags: jsf-2

JSF2 configuration confusion. Some concepts like the validator, converter have ID's. They can be linked to the UIComponents using their ID. Other concepts like the ValueChangeListener, ActionListener can be linked to the UIComponents using the classname. Is there a reason for these different ways to configure things, or is it just inconsistent? Is there a reason why validators, converters, composite components have ID' while listeners don't have ID's? I would like to clear things out because it might point to a nuance I didn't understand.